# Assign variable within kubernetes yaml job

Tags: awk, kubernetes

I would like to run a command within the yaml file for kubernetes:

Here is the part of the yaml file that i use
The idea is to calculate a precent value based on mapped and unmapped values. mapped and unmapped are set properly but the percent line fails
I think the problem comes from the single quotes in the BEGIN statement of the awk command which i guess need to escape ???

If mapped=8 and unmapped=7992
Then percent is (8/(8+7992)*100) = 0.1%

```
  command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
            args: [' 
                ...
                echo "Executing command" &&
                map=${grep -c "^@" outfile.mapped.fq} &&
                unmap=${grep -c "^@" outfile.unmapped.fq} && 
                percent=$(awk -v CONVFMT="%.10g" -v map="$map" -v unmap="$unmap" "BEGIN { print ((map/(unmap+map))*100)}") &&


                echo "finished" 
                  ']
```

Comment: Try `awk -v CONVFMT="%.10g" -v map="$map" -v unmap="$unmap"  "BEGIN { print   ((map/(unmap+map))*100)}"`. idk what kubernetes is but if it's some kind of shell then you can't escape single quotes inside single-quote delimited strings and that's what you appear to have with `args: [' ... ']`. If it IS like shell then you could alternatively replace every internal `'` with `'\''`.

Comment: I do suggest you do not use old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this, `map=$(grep -c "^@" outfile.mapped.fq) &&`

Comment: This will be much easier to handle if you build it into a separate script and bake it into a Docker image, rather than trying to write the whole thing inline in the Kubernetes YAML syntax.  Given what you're doing a higher-level language like Python (with built-in file I/O and mathematical functions) might also be a better match than a shell script.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton and @Jotne 
The following command written properly worked well !!!
          `percent=$(awk -v CONVFMT="%.10g" -v map="$map" -v unmap="$unmap" "BEGIN { print ((map/(unmap+map))*100)}") && `

@david-maze thought about your option but requires recreating a docker image everytime you modify your code. Instead i rather have the code in gitlab and download the scripts as appropriate when needed using gitlab containers.

Comment: BTW @EdMorton , surronding my code with `args: [' ... '] ` was the only way i found to support env values. For exemple if you have the following code
  `env:
        - name: CPUS
          value: "3"
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args:['
            echo "CPUS: $CPUS" &&
           ....`

Don´t know how to deal with env variables without the args block within single quotes ??

Comment: I´ve edited the code as suggested. Everything working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the community comments: [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) & [david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494621/david)

For those files with data, please create configmap:

```
outfile.mapped.fq
outfile.unmapped.fq

kubectl create configmap config-volume --from-file=/path_to_directory_with_files/
```

Create pod:

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata: 
  name: awk-ubu 
spec: 
  containers: 
    - name: awk-ubuntu 
      image: ubuntu 
      workingDir: /test
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ] 
      args: 
        - echo Executing_command; 
          map=$(grep -c "^@" outfile.mapped.fq); 
          unmap=$(grep -c "^@" outfile.unmapped.fq); 
          percent=$(awk -v CONVFMT="%.10g" -v map="$map" -v unmap="$unmap" "BEGIN { print ((map/(unmap+map))*100)}"); 
          echo $percent;  
          echo Finished; 
      volumeMounts: 
      - name: special-config 
        mountPath: /test 
  volumes: 
    - name: special-config 
      configMap: 
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want 
        # to add to the container 
        name: config-volume 
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Once completed verify the result:

```
kubectl logs awk-ubu

Executing_command
53.3333
Finished
```